# SoapUI thread vs server process thread

Tags: multithreading, soapui

I have an API request when posted from a client to a server get executed with a max thread count of 8. I tried to simulate webservice API call using soapUI and I am able to succeed in that task.

Now my task is to perform a simple load test using soapUI. In soapUI, I have an option set the thread count and what I understand from soapUI documentation is threads are virtual users like load generators.

My question is if I run the load test in soapUI with a thread count of 8 will it simulate the server thread process which I described above.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily (but likely). If your server can handle the requests faster than the client sends them, you won't get 8 simultaneous server threads handling requests.

If you really want to see what's going on server side when load testing a SoapUI TestCase, the easiest option would be using LoadUI Pro, which can show you how many threads are being used by the server.

*Source/Disclaimer: I professionally develop LoadUI and SoapUI.*